# Finding a basis for a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

From what I know, a basis is a linearly independent spanning set. And a spanning set is just all the linear combinations of the vectors.

Lets say we have the two vectors

$a =(1,2)$
$b =(2,1)$

So I will assume that the first step involves proving that the vectors are linearly independent

x(1,2)+ y(2,1) = (0,0)

After doing row reduction, i found out that the vectors are linearly independent because the only solutions for x and y are 0

I'm not sure what to do next. I know how to determine if a set of vectors forms a basis over a vectors space $R^n$, but to actually find a basis of a set of vectors is a little different for me.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You’re confusing “span” with “spanning set.” The *span* of a set of vectors is the set of all of their linear combinations; a *spanning set* is a set of vectors whose span covers some given larger set.

Comment: Hint: A useful thing to remember here is the definition of the dimension of a vector space. Also, there’s no need to perform row-reduction when all you’ve got is a pair of vectors: they are linearly dependent iff one is a scalar multiple of the other.

Comment: Consider the vectors $(1,0,0)^T$ and $(0,1,0)^T$ in $\mathtt R^3$. Their span is the $x$-$y$ plane. Obviously, then, these two vectors are a spanning set of this plane, but so are the sets $\{(2,1,0)^T,(1,2,0)^T\}$, $\{(1,1,0)^T,(-1,1,0)^T,(3,5,0)^T,(-1,-4,0)^T\}$ and so on, as the span of all of these sets is also the $x$-$y$ plane. Not all of these sets are linearly independent, though, so not all of them will be *bases* for the space.

Comment: I understand now, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're done.

You're working in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so any basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ will contain two linearly independent vectors. After showing that your system admits only the trivial solution, you're found that those two vectors are linearly independent (and since there's exactly two, form a spanning set). This is enough to find a basis.

Now, in general, if you have more than the required number of vectors to build a basis, you can figure out which ones are a linear combination of the others and remove them from the set in question. This is something many linear algebra texts have as exercises. You can even extend a linearly independent set of vectors to a basis for a vector space by means of Gram-Schmidt or some other process. Just have to be careful!

Comment: So just to be sure, the basis of the two vectors (1,2) and (2,1) are the vectors (1,2) and (2,1) because the two vectors are a spanning set that is linearly independent?

Comment: No - the basis for their span is just that. Span, as a noun, means "all linear combinations;" span as a verb means "to encompass; any vector in the space can be built from these."